# When does JSF evaluate EL expressions

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, el

For a deferred EL expression, JSF will evaluate it many times during a single request. I've checked the JavaEE tutorial, it says :

> For a postback request, the JavaServer Faces implementation evaluates
>   the expression at different phases of the lifecycle, during which the
>   value is retrieved from the request, validated, and propagated to the
>   customer bean.

So does it mean JSF will evaluate EL expressions 3 times in a single request? This could probably be a potential performance problem.

For example, we can retrieve a collection of entities by using `#{userList.resultList}`  expression. JSF evaluates it 3 times, that's to say, database will be consulted 3 times in a single request. How to avoid this  redundant database query?

Thanks!

Comment: It's more like 6 than 3. You can avoid it by only doing major work like database lookups in the render-response phase.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EL should use simple getters/setters.. Don't put business logic inside your getters so userList.resultList should simply -return resultList that was set into the bean upon initialisation.

Refer to: [Why JSF calls getters multiple times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2090033/why-jsf-calls-getters-multiple-times/2090062#2090062)

I could cut and paste and go on about this, but its all been explained exceptionally well in the above post by BalusC